# How to make objects collide in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

Recently I've been trying to make a 2D game in XNA, but I seem to have hit a dead end. No mater where I look on the internet, I can't seem to find any examples of how to make two objects collide in XNA. I know perfectly well about how to detect if something is colliding, just not what to put between the `if` statement.

In my case it's trying to make a player not pass through any blocks on the screen. I've tried several ways, but none of them seems to work. :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, it's 2D! I should have explained.

Comment: are all your obstacles rectangular (ie blocks) or do you have diagonals?

Comment: All rectangular; I'm not ready for exact pixel collision yet, just using `Rectangle()` bounds.

Comment: what type of game is it? platformer?

Comment: No, but it requires a player to jump on a few blocks here and there.

Comment: The 'correct' thing to do is impulse resolution, but by the sounds of things you probably haven't looked much into game physics yet.

Comment: _"No mater where I look on the internet, I can't seem to find any **examples of how to make two objects collide in XNA**"_ - using your words _[examples of how to make two objects collide in XNA](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=examples+of+how+to+make+two+objects+collide+in+XNA&rlz=1C1CHMD_enAU565AU565&oq=examples+of+how+to+make+two+objects+collide+in+XNA&aqs=chrome..69i57.1889j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)_ I found quite a few very easily

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: @MickyDuncan I tried nearly all of these, and none of them seemed to work for the stye of code I was using, but the answer below seems just fine!

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is sort of a dirty solution, but you could save the position of where you are, move, and then if you collide, revert back to the original position.

Here's a code example, providing your method to check for collision is called `doesCollide()` and your method to do the game logic and move the player accordingly is called `update()`.

Also, getX(), getY(), setX() and setY() are just methods to get/set the coordinates of the player.

```
int lastX = player.getX();
int lastY = player.getY();

player.update();
if(player.doesCollide()){
    player.setX(lastX);
    player.setY(lastY);
}
```

This method especially faces problems, when the player is moving at a high speed, because then the player might glitch through obstacles or not be able to get close to walls.
Here's a solution that fixes that, but it is even dirtier:

```
int lastX = player.getX();
int lastY = player.getY();

player.update();

int moveX = player.getX() - lastX;
int moveY = player.getY() - lastY;

player.setX(lastX);
player.setY(lastY);    //we're basically figuring out where the player would move

int ratio = moveY / moveX;
for(int i = 0; i < moveX; i++){     //we move the player pixel by pixel
    player.setX(lastX + i);
    player.setY(lastY + (int) (i * ratio));
    if(player.doesCollide()){     //we revert the last pixel move
         player.setX(lastX + i - 1);
         player.setY(lastY + (int) ((i - 1) * ratio));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? How would I undo it?

Comment: you'd save the position of the player before movement, then move the player, then test whether there is a collision in the new position, and then if there is a collision reset the player's position back to the start. This will automatically block the player from moving into an obstacle.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense I suppose. So how do I do this?

Comment: write a method that tests if the player's box is colliding with any of the obstacle boxes. then in the movement method after you update the player's position, call that method to find out if the player has collided. If the player has collided then set the player's position back to what it was